# How can I get pairs of words from a sentence with NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to take in a sentence:

```
sentence = "How many people are here"?
```

and return a list of phrases:

```
pairs = ["How many", "many people", "people are", "are here"]
```

I tried

```
   tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
   pairs = nltk.bigrams(tokens)
```

and instead got `<generator object bigrams at 0x103697820>`

Im pretty new to nltk so sorry that this is so off :) Help appreciated!

Comment: did you try `list(pairs)` or call `next(pairs)` to iterate through the generator, on the resulting generator object?

Comment: Ah great. How do i transform it into the form that I want i.e. from [('How', 'many')] --> ["How many"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, the `nktk.bigrams()` function returns a generator object.
Generators need to be iterated through in order to get the values out.   This can be done with `list()`, or by looping over the generator.

Below, I'm looping/iterating over the generator object (results of `nktk.bigrams()` ) in a list comprehension, while at the same time using `"".join()` to combine the pair (list) of words, shed by the generator, into a single string, as desired.

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
pairs = [ " ".join(pair) for pair in nltk.bigrams(tokens)]
```

> > ['How many', ...]

Comment: do you want to fill this out with your first comment so i can accept? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
import re
f = open('D:\Jupyter notebook\SNPQ.txt','r')
text = f.read()
text = re.sub('^\n|\n$','',(text))
for no,line in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
    print('"'+'","'.join([i.replace('"','\\"').strip() for i in re.split('(?<=^[0-9]{2})([0-9]{13}| {13})|  +',text.splitlines()[no].strip()) if i != None])+'"')
```

Thank you :)